# Split string into 2 elements

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am trying to split a string into 2 part if first part of string match '`begin`'

I have

```
var str = 'beginThetest';
```

I want to get an `array` like `['begin','Thetest'];`

I have tried `substring` and `split` but it doesn't seem to work in my case.

Are there any ways to do this? Thanks a lot!

Comment: What are the rules for splitting the string into 2 parts?

Comment: we need more information. what do you want to split on? the first capital character?

Comment: Sorry, the begin is the keyword. every time a string begin with 'begin' will be divided into 2 elements and begin will always be the first element.

Comment: Then why not: `array = ['begin', str.substr(5)]`?

Comment: And what could be the interest to get an array here if you already know value of first element of the array and expect to get only two items in this array??? Just a `var newstr = str.replace('begin','')` couldn't be enough?

Comment: @roasted not for a string like `beginThetestbegin` :)

Comment: @sgroves why not? replace() can be used with regex too

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do this with the [`String.split`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/split) function, which splits a string into an array using a separator/token:

```
var token = 'begin';
var str = 'beginThetest';
var parts = str.split(token);

alert(parts[0]);   //'Thetest'
```

---

If you don't fully understand `String.split`:

The `parts` array only contains one element (`parts[0]`) because there are no characters before the only occurrence of the token (`'begin'`) in your string.

A lengthier example should make this clear:

```
var token = 'begin';
var str = 'THIS_TESTbeginTHAT_TESTbeginLAST_TEST';
var parts = str.split(token);

alert(parts[0]);   //'THIS_TEST'
alert(parts[1]);   //'THAT_TEST'
alert(parts[2]);   //'LAST_TEST'
```

---

But if `'begin'` is always your token, what's the point? You don't need to `split`, you can just do something like:

```
var str = 'beginThetest';
var token = 'begin';
var index = token.length;

var the_rest = str.substr(index);
alert(the_rest);    //'Thetest'
```

And of course you can put that into an array if you'd like.

Answer (score 1):

Might be a little bit dirty, but it works :)

```
var str = 'beginThetest';
var splitter = 'begin';
var array = str.split(splitter);
array[0] = splitter;

console.warn(array);
```

Answer (score 1):

```
var parts = splitter("beginThetest", "begin");


function splitter(input, term)
{
    var ret = new Array();

    var index = input.indexOf(term);

    if(index != -1)
    {
        ret.push(input.substring(index, term.length));
        ret.push(input.substring(index + term.length, input.length));
    }    

    return ret;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try using slice with a check for 'begin':

```
var str = 'beginThetest',
    arr = [],
    breakChar = 5;

if(str.slice(0,breakChar) == 'begin'){

    arr.push( str.slice(0,breakChar) );

    arr.push( str.slice(breakChar) );

}
```